# Moving the visible area of QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class based on `QGraphicsView`. I want to make the clicks on WASD move the visible scene to the appropriate direction. The task is simple and clear, wrote the following code:

```
GameScene::GameScene(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(scene, parent) {
    _scene = scene;

    _resolution = new QPointF(1920, 1080);
    _position = new QPointF(100, 100);
    setSceneRect(_position->x(), _position->y(), _resolution->x(), _resolution->y());

    installEventFilter(this);

    scene->addItem(new QGraphicsLineItem(510, 510, 990, 990)); }

void GameScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_W:
        _position->setY(_position->y() - 100);
        break;

    case Qt::Key_S:
        _position->setY(_position->y() + 100);
        break;

    case Qt::Key_A:
        _position->setX(_position->x() - 100);
        break;

    case Qt::Key_D:
        _position->setX(_position->x() + 100);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    setSceneRect(_position->x(), _position->y(), _resolution->x(), _resolution->y());
    update(); 
}
```

This code even works, but there is one problem: the scene does not always respond to the `setSceneRect` function (checked through the debagger signal reaches, the values are sent to the function correct), that is, the key is pressed, the `keyPressEvent` function is executed, the desired case is selected, the values are updated, but the `setSceneRect` function does not do anything. What could be the problem?

Comment: why `installEventFilter(this);`?

Comment: @TFM but in `keyPressEvent` changing only posotion. resolution doesn't changing

Comment: @argbt1 Ah, yes sorry, I misread...

Comment: @eyllanesc without this line, the signals do not reach at all. Is this the right wayr?

Comment: @argbt1 
What signal are you referring to ?, keyPressEvent is an event, and you should only use installEventFilter when an object wants to *listen* the events of another object, in which case it is not necessary because the object can *listen* to its own events. Also when using installEventFilter you must overwrite the eventFilter method, read the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, i delete this line. It really works the same way. Thanks. But the problem still remains :(

Comment: @argbt1 When your question talks about the signal, I suppose it refers to the `sceneRectChanged` signal, how do you verify that the `setSceneRect()` function does not work ?, you do not show proof of that failure.

Comment: @argbt1 a question, does the width and height of the sceneRect have to change?

Comment: @eyllanesc no, only position

Comment: @argbt1 
Why do you say it does not work? What exactly does not work?

Comment: @eyllanesc When I press WASD the scene sometimes does not react immediately. That is: I clamp -> passes 1.5 - 2.5 seconds -> the scene starts moving. But this is not always the case. Sometimes the scene is triggered instantly.

Comment: @argbt1 
test my solution, how many items do you have ?, are you doing another task?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, but i get the same result :(

Comment: @argbt1 Without answers to my questions, little or nothing can help you, **do you have more tasks in your application? How many items do you have in the scene? What is your OS ?, etc**, there are many things that could cause that problem, without a [mcve] nobody can help you.